# Xpath Xmlx (Output Error) ['RM\u202f649']

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<div class="product-info ncss-col-sm-12 full" xpath="1"><h1 class="headline-5 pb3-sm">Air More Uptempo</h1><h5 class="headline-1 pb3-sm">Black</h5><div class="headline-5 pb6-sm fs14-sm fs16-md">RM 649</div><div class="test-available-date"><div class="available-date-component">Available 20/11 at 10:00 am</div></div><div class="description-text text-color-grey"><p>More than perhaps any other silhouette, the Air More Uptempo encapsulates '90s basketball footwear at its finest. Big and bold, the design unapologetically represents a hybrid of style and innovation that made major waves upon its debut—and still turns heads over 20 years later. This OG colourway sees the style covered in neutral black with crisp highlights of contrasting white.</p></div></div>
```

Source code can read from above.

**Code**

```
price = tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'product-info')]/div[1]/text()")
print(price)
```

**Output**

```
['RM\u202f649']
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add desired output.

Comment: Your input XML contains some invisible character (\u202f) between RM and 649. That is a reason why you are getting such output on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Your input XML contains an invisible character (\u202f) between RM and 649. That is a reason why you are getting such output on your end.

Please try the following XPath 2.0:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'product-info')]/div[1]/text() cast as xs:token?
```